# Unable to set the flash message in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

i am working on cakePHP session setFlash(),it does not display the message on the view
  i read the session it contains the message.My message,

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Uploaded the file successfully.', Messages::MSG_INFO);
```

i checked the session,

```
LogUtil::$logger->debug('Session Data     :'.var_export($this->Session->read('Message'),true));
```

The Result of the Above Logger is,

```
array (
    'auth' => array (
        'message' => 'Login failed. Invalid username or password.',
        'element' => 'msg_error',
        'params' => array (),
    ),
    'flash' => array (
        'message' => 'Uploaded the file successfully.',
        'element' => 'msg_info',
        'params' => array (),
    ),
 )
```

please help me why the flash message is not displayed.

Comment: `LogUtil::$logger->debug` what's wrong with `debug($foo)` ? Are you redirecting inbetween calling setFlash and expecting to see the flash message, or in the same request? Where is your log call?

Answer (score 2):

have you write

```
var $helpers = array('Session');
```

in your controller?

If you you have declared it, did you try echoing

```
$this->Session->flash()
```

in your view?

there might be causes to display message in view files.